# How do I make a 3D table using Processing.JS?

Tags: processing, processing.js

I want to run a for loop that will have a line with a color of brown. This line will get smaller and smaller, but not too small.

The final image will look like this, but with the table top being colored in brown:

```javascript
//Back wall
fill(102, 102, 102);
rect(50,50,300,300);
//Top Left Corner
line(50,50,0,0);
//Top Right Corner
line(350,50,400,0);
//Bottom Left Corner
line(350,350,400,400);
//Bottom Riight Corner
line(50,350,0,400);

//Table
//Top Left
fill(48, 17, 0);
rect(163,312,3,38);
//Top Right
fill(48, 17, 0);
rect(230,312,3,38);
//Mesa
fill(48, 17, 0);
rect(126,322,142,5);
//Right Side
line(126,322,168,312);
//Top Side
line(234,312,168,312);
//Right Side
line(269,322,232,312);
//Bottom Left Leg
rect(126,327,5,41);
line(126,368,126,322);
//Bottom Right Leg
rect(263,327,5,41);
line(269,368,268,322);
```

I have tried this for loop:

```javascript
for(var x = 200; x > 100; x--){

 stroke(61, 34, 0);
 line(x,200,x,200);

}
```

The x value will decrease until x = 100. But, it is not showing the the line getting smaller EVEN after making sure the background(); is out of the loop.

P.S. The pieces of code given are separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only changing the `x` coordinate of the lines you're drawing, so the line is moving horizontally, not vertically.

If you want the line to move vertically (to color in the table) and horizontally (to make it smaller as it gets "further away"), you'll have to change both the `x` and `y` values you pass into the `line()` function.

But you're making this harder than it needs to be. There is no reason for you to draw a bunch of lines to get this shape. Just use the **[`beginShape()`](http://processingjs.org/reference/beginShape_/)** function to draw the polygon directly. Something like this:

```javascript
  beginShape();
  vertex(100, 100); //upper-left
  vertex(200, 100); //upper-right
  vertex(250, 200); //lower-right
  vertex(50, 200); //lower=left
  endShape(CLOSE);
```

Note that this is just an example, and you'll have to play around with the values to draw it in the correct location. But the point is that you don't have to use a for loop to draw lines just to draw a polygon.

Since you're trying to draw a 3D scene, you should also note that you can simply use 3D coordinates along with the [`vertex()`](http://processingjs.org/reference/vertex_/) function to draw in 3D. No need to try to force the perspective yourself.